# How to pass on data from DIV to input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I`m using bootstrap date picker which is described in DIV:

```html
<form action="" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal pull-left">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="bfh-datepicker"  data-format="y-m-d" data-date="today">
</div>
<input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My goal is to get data from that DIV and insert it in to database. The one option what comes in to my mind I could add one hidden input field in the form and pass on the data from DIV in to input field  somehow. Then using GET method in PHP I could get the data from that input field. Can someone guide me how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked ath the documentation? Seems like you can do $('.bfh-datepicker').datepicker('getdate');

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdate

Comment: Just put the datepicker on the input element itself instead of the div. Then you won't have any data moving to do.

Comment: @RogiSolorzano I tried instead of:

<div class="bfh-datepicker"  data-format="y-m-d" data-date="today"></div>


To do like that: 
         

<input type="text" name="lname" class="bfh-datepicker"  data-format="y-m-d" data-date="today">


But the datepicker doesn’t work like that. It showing just regular text input field. What I do wrong?

Comment: @juju is this a java script? I`m using PHP and usually get data from input fields using GET method like that $name=$_GET['name']. Can you guide me how to write a code to get data from DIV? Is this $name=$('.bfh-datepicker').datepicker('getdate')?